# Embedding Metadata to H.264 encoded file

Tags: android, ffmpeg, metadata, h.264, encode

I am currently developing an application which produces certain metadata with respect to preview frames coming from the camera. I can see this metadata being produced properly and I have no problems here.

However, I have to embed this metadata to these frames of interest (frames are processed by a native algorithm to produce this metadata). I am using ffmpeg with x264 to encode  the frames into H.264. I have checked x264.h and some documentations but failed to find what I seek.

My question is; is there any unused portion of H.264 syntax that  I can embed my metadata to encoded frames?

I hope I was clear enough. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at this http://atomicparsley.sourceforge.net/ ... or this http://www.brooksandrus.com/blog/2007/08/29/a-quick-look-at-h264-metadata/

But i don't know if you'll find your answer there as I'm only familiar with providing metadata while streaming (either with live555 or any RTSP really)

Comment: New release of ffmpeg has as the first bullet point of new features: "Bitstream filters for editing metadata in H.264, HEVC and MPEG-2 streams" http://ffmpeg.org/index.html#pr4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most video elementary streams have a provision for "user data".  In h.264 this is part of the SEI nal unit. You can add one before every frame you want to associate it with. I don't think that x264 has support to add user data from outside.

Two choices:

1. Modify x264 / ffmpeg to add the SEI message where ever you want it taking input in some form you like.
2. Create your stream, create your metadata. Now write a small program separately to read your metadata and parse the files and push a SEI NAL before the frame you want.

For SEI syntax you should be able to google and get it. The best place to look though is the H.264 standard. A easier way is to just look at the code in x264. It does insert one user data at the begining (the encoding parameters).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look into it right away. You save the day once more av501 :)

Comment: Welcome. The second method will only work for an elementary stream. Forgot to mention that. In a container you also have to take care of the container itself.

Comment: @user1767754, not sure what you want there. Mostly timecode information is standard information available within stream or the enclosing container. So for now I am guessing that would be duplication of effort. You need to be more specific on what you want to store. You can store anything but since it is user data no one understands it except you and your code on the decoding side if you control the decoder!