# ffmpeg H264 - How to add user unregistered SEI Message while encoding stream

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, video-encoding

I'm working on an application where I need to insert some user unregistered SEI data in every frame before encoding it. I can't seem to find any API to add the SEI data. What I need to do is probably option 1 to the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320604/embedding-metadata-to-h-264-encoded-file/12323091#12323091?newreg=1b43b1fb9ef04bf2a065363b747773f1); but I'm not sure on how to proceed.?

I've tried setting "sei" through the AvCodecContext priv_data, using av_opt_set as follows: (as well as changing the parameters quite a bit).

```
AVCodecContext* c;

char *sei_msg = (char *)malloc(lenData);   // just a sample usage of how...
memcpy(sei_msg, data, lenData);            // ...i have my sei_message

av_opt_set(c,"sei", sei_msg, 0)
```

Not sure if this is the correct direction for this?

How do I set the data that i'm adding is a Nal of type SEI (6) and that the SEI is of type User_Data_Unregistered (5). And then go about adding this data?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing. Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: After checking up the c->priv_data and how libx264 uses it, managed a simple hack by explicitly memcpy'ing the required data to the memory location. Not sure if that's the right way to proceed though.
Also, this works for me on linux but not on windows. I have no clue why, still trying to get it to work on windows (where the rest of my codebase lies :( )

Comment: I'm trying to extract unregistered user data SEI, do you know how to do that?